# How to process database changes using Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark

If I have an RDD that depends on a database table, how do I listen to DB changes through Spark Streaming and reconstruct the RDD when the table changes?

Answer (score 1):

Without reinventing wheel you can use http://data.linkedin.com/projects/databus from inside Spark